# need regex for form validation to avoid multiple special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need jquery or javascript regex to validate form text box so that if any one will enter multiple times same special characters an alert will be generated.

For example
how are you??
or
how are you....
or 
how are you@@??

Please note that I need to block "multiple" use of special characters I don't want to block single special character. If one need to send "hello how are you?" it should be proceed.

Thank you,

**[Update]**
I got the final result

To validate form text box for all special characters we can use

```
/(?! )(\W)\1+/
```

To validate some special characters we can use

```
/([@#$%])\1+/;
```

Add or remove special characters inside **[ ]**

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, please clearly define the set of "special characters".

Comment: I think you may be mistaking this site for the rent a coder site

Comment: I tried this /^([@?#$%])\1{1,}$/; but didn't worked

Comment: @Suhaib: You're very close. Remove `^` and `$` and it should work. Btw `{1,} == +`

Comment: @elclanrs thanks a million dear, really appreciate your help I did according to your guidance and it worked perfectly fine my final change is as follow   /([@#$%])\1+/;

Answer (score 0):

Try the reverse: take the input, filter out all characters you *want*, and see if the length of "the rest" is greater than, or equal, to 2.

Answer (score 0):

This regex should work assuming special characters is anything but letters, numbers and spaces:

```
/(?! )(\W)\1+/
```

Comment: thanks alot I tried this and it worked great. Can you please tell me if I can do some change in the above regex to define some special characters? like if I only need to validate !@#$%?

Comment: I'll leave that up to you. You can learn about regex at http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 0):

On submit events, ensure that there are no invalid characters in the textbox. You can prevent the submit via `return`ing `false` from the handler.

HTML:

```
<input type='text' id='yourTextboxID' />
<input type='submit' id='submitButton' value='Submit' />
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('submitButton').onclick = function () {
    var enteredValue = document.getElementById('yourTextboxID').value;

    if (enteredValue.test(/[!@#$%^&*()]+/)) {
        alert('Bad characters!');
        return false;
    }

    return true;
};
```

You can modify and test the regex [here](http://regexr.com?33ans) if you desire.